# Adding two horizontal lines to a loglinear plot in mathematica using the Epilog command

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Regarding a loglinear plot in Mathematica, how can two horizontal lines be added using the Epilog command?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 0.1, 100},
 PlotRange -> {{0.1, 100}, {0, 1}},
 Epilog -> {
   Line[{{0, 0.6}, {100, 0.6}}],
   Line[{{0, 0.4}, {100, 0.4}}]}]
```

[image]

The added lines begins at x = 1 because e^0 = 1.